# iOS「（シーン）A->B->C」 modalを重ねた遷移した「シーンC」でunwind segueを使うと「シーンB」が一瞬表示される

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, storyboard

storyboardを使いviewController（=シーン）A,B,Cを作成し A->B->Cとmodalでsegueをつなぎます。
シーンBとシーンCともにシーンAへ戻るためunwind segueを作成しました。
シーンCからシーンAへ戻る際に、シーンBが下部へ消えていくアニメーションが一瞬表示されます。
シーンBが見えないようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

イメージとしては

- シーンA：スタート画面
- シーンB：ゲームプレイ画面
- シーンC：結果画面

です。よろしくお願いします。

※NavigationCotrollerかと考えましたが、上段のNavigation Barが不要なため質問しました。